# How do I find Java dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am following [this](http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/03/03/kafka-spark-avro-consume-messages-with-spark.html) tutorial. The code I have is this:

```
package com.ipponusa;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

public class SparkStringConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("kafka-sandbox")
                .setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));

        // TODO: processing pipeline

        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

My Maven dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that the code and imports all have errors. I don't know what dependencies I need, and I don't know how to find out what dependencies I need. I am new to Java.

So my question is, how am I supposed to know what dependencies I need?

Note: Neither IntelliJ or Netbeans "Find Maven Dependency" features found anything for me.

Edit: If I go [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) I can find the Classes I am looking for, but I can't find the dependencies there.

Edit: If I go [here](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=org.apache.spark) I can find a long list of dependencies, but I can't find the ones that have the classes I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can search for the dependencies in maven repository [here](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=org.apache.spark)

Comment: How do I search for a specific thing like **import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;**? When I tried no results were shown.

Comment: Maven repo search queries are groups and artifacts. we cant have FQN there :(

Comment: So is there a way to find it without trying every last **org.apache.spark** result?

Comment: Can you check adding the artifact `spark-streaming_2.10`? I've udated the dependency in the answer below.

Comment: go to search.maven.org . Click advanced search and provide your fully qualified name in `By ClassName` text box. It will list all the jars-version that has your classes. You can then download the appropriate jar .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add the spark core too

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Are there other dependencies I may need? Also, how do you find out what dependencies you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'search by classname' feature of [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) to find the library you need to import.

Also keep in mind that maven dependencies are transitive, i.e. a dependency of a dependency is included in your project too.

Answer (score 0):

Not really Maven-specific, but you can look at the [Spark source repo](https://github.com/apache/spark), search for the class you want, then look roughly at the folder that it is in.

For example, `SparkContext` exists under the `core/` folder.

Note: `spark-streaming-kafka` *depends on* `spark-streaming`, which *depends on* `spark-core`, so if you included that, or the other core libraries like MLlib, SparkSQL, or GraphX, then core should be brought in as well.

Perhaps you needed to run `mvn compile`